# Can a OIDC JWT identity claim (such as phonenumber or email) be multiple?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, claims-based-identity, claims

Shortly, is such a OIDC JWT payload valid?

```
{
   "sub"                     : "alice",
   "email"                   : ["alice@wonderland.net", "alice@wherever.com"],
   ...
}
```

Reading the official RFCs, I could only find that the keys (`sub`, `email` etc.) must be unique, but nothing about the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `email` claim is required to be a string. So an array is not a valid value, as per the [OpenID Connect Core 1.0 spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) (formatting is mine):

> **email**
> string
>
> End-User's preferred e-mail address. Its value MUST conform to the [RFC
> 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) addr-spec syntax. The RP MUST NOT rely upon this value
> being unique, as discussed in [Section 5.7](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClaimStability).

In the [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), the *addr-spec* syntax is defined as follows:

> An addr-spec is a specific Internet identifier that contains a locally
> interpreted string followed by the at-sign character (`@`,  ASCII
> value 64) followed by an Internet domain. [...]
>
> ````
> addr-spec       =   local-part "@" domain
>
> local-part      =   dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part
>
> domain          =   dot-atom / domain-literal / obs-domain
>
> domain-literal  =   [CFWS] "[" *([FWS] dtext) [FWS] "]" [CFWS]
>
> dtext           =   %d33-90 /          ; Printable US-ASCII
>                     %d94-126 /         ;  characters not including
>                     obs-dtext          ;  "[", "]", or "\" ```
> ````

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather say email claim value could be an array. [OIDC doc](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims) states only that type must be  string (not int, bool, etc.), but it doesn't actually specify if it can or cannot be an array.

But for other standard claims, like `given_name` doc implies that values could be an array:

> Given name(s) or first name(s) of the End-User...